# Remove site guest user and add a vf page in Sites

Tags: administration, force.com-sites

In a developer instance when I click on site

`http://developersite-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/devaddress`

I'm getting a guest user site page.

But when I click on that site link I have to remove the guest user page and need to display a VF page.

Any Ideas.

Comment: unclear what you are asking. Can you specify more details?

Are you trying to add a visualforce page to a site so it can be accessed without having to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The page that is visible on click of site link can be configured.As in the above snapshot you will need to replace your Active Site Home Page with your Vf page.

Make sure you have proper access of page given to guest user.Also please make sure you have proper acess of the objects your Vf is refering to the Guest User Profile.

Comment: When I clicked on the link it should display as an external site....no salesforce look should come in it

Comment: You can always style your Vf using proper CSS if you dont want salesforce look.You may want to look at the following website support.activision.com .This uses sites but we have changed the look and feel.Thanks